# Is "viewing something pictorially" redundant?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, redundancy

Say that there is some concept X which I want to expose to the reader to as such:

> (formal explanation of X)
>
> Viewing X pictorially:
>
> (depiction of X in an image)

An example of X would be a mathematical function.

Is saying "viewing X pictorially" redundant, or does "viewing" not imply the use of imagery to depict some concept?

Comment: You could make a mental picture of something in which case you ain't seeing it pictorially. So the question of redundancy or not depends on more information.

Comment: 'Illustrating (a relation, a trend, say) pictorially' similarly pinpoints the non-metaphorical usage of the verb.

Comment: Try: *Viewing X schematically:*

Comment: If you can view X as an equation or as a picture, then it seems reasonable to differentiate it. "View" is quite general (you can view something as numbers or statistics, as a schematic diagram, as a graph, on a screen, in 3D, in the flesh, etc.)